# How to loop through a dataframe after using the split function

Tags: r, split

i want to split my dataframe according to groups (using "split" function) and then loop through those groups with an other function. as an example i here used the "nrow" function and the iris data and split them by spceies

```
df <- split(iris, iris$Species)

for (i in 1:lenght(df)) {
nrow(df[i])
}
```

now this doesnt work, what does work as i cannot access df[1] with nrow. however i can acess df$"setosa"

```
nrow(df$"setosa")
```

would produce the desired outcome "[1] 50", however i cant loop through it this way.
is there any solution as to how to be able to loop through the split dataframes in any way?

thank you for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lenght` should be `length` and the `[` should be `[[`

```
for(i in 1:length(df)) print(nrow(df[[i]]))
```

Or instead of `1:length`, it can be more correct with `seq_along`

```
for(i in seq_along(df)) print(nrow(df[[i]]))
```

The `df[i]` is still a `list` of 1 element whereas `df[[i]]` extracts the `list` element to get the data.frame.  That is the reason `nrow(df[i])` didn't work because it is a `list` and there is no dim attribute for a `list`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works! why is it more correct with seq_along?

Comment: @Duesser it is just that if you have a list of length 0. 1:0 returns 1, 0

Comment: thanks you! i was unable to check earlier, it said i would have to wait a couple more minutes :) have a nice day

Comment: @Duesser thank you.  Have a great day to you as well!